# cytoscape.js disable grab&moving nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm having trouble building a graph network with cytoscapeJS.
I can add nodes and handle them which is quite easy, but I'm not able to configure cytospace to disable Dragging/Moving nodes.

I have found a JSbin from somebody where you can try: http://jsbin.com/vasenatimu/2/edit?html,js,output

Have a look at http://js.cytoscape.org under 'Initialisation options', I tried all the options, but they dont solve my problem (I set nearly all options to false and I can still grab and select nodes).

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`initOptions.autoungrabify: true` or `cy.nodes().ungrabify()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable selected nodes using their configuration. For example:

```js
cytoscape({
  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { 
        data: { id: "node1" }, 
        grabbable: false,
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I found out this is the solution to the problem for me:

```
cytoscape({
  autolock: true, <== this did the trick for me
  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { 

      },
    ],
  },
});
```

I hope this will help you as well.

Regards Edgar